# Block level links glitches on width and height transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have a problem with transition of width and height on li items. The margin-bottom of the links kind of glitches and flickers. It's not easy to explain so I took a video of it. Look at it here (watch the social sites links):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SAB0CqmID4

The first browser is Chrome, the second is Firefox. Strangely, the glitch isn't happening in Firefox, but in other browsers, it does (Chrome, Safari, Opera).

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class="social">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook centered"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter centered"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-google-plus centered"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS (Sass)

```
.social {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 45px;
    z-index: 100;

    li {
        display: block;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        opacity: 0.5;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 32px;
        transition: width 2s ease-in, height 2s ease-in, font-size 2s ease-in, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;

        a {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    }

    li:hover {
        opacity: 0.9;
        transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }

    .fa-facebook {
        background: #3B5998;
    }
    .fa-twitter {
        background: #55acee;
    }
    .fa-google-plus {
        background: #d34836;
    }
}

.social-small li {
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    font-size: 22px;
    transition: width 2s ease-out, height 2s ease-out, font-size 2s ease-out, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT (jQuery) - to start the transition on scroll

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var hT = $('#hero').offset().top,
        hH = $('#hero').outerHeight(),
        wH = $(window).height(),
        wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (wS > (hT+hH-wH+45)){
        $(".social").addClass("social-small");
    }
    else {
        $(".social").removeClass("social-small");
    }
    if (wS > (hT+hH-wH+27)){
        $(".site-nav").addClass("site-nav-small");
    }
    else {
        $(".site-nav").removeClass("site-nav-small");
    }            
});
```

Any ideas how to fix it? Is the case just that Firefox had worked out this glitch?

Thank you.

Comment: Your video is private, maybe li {overflow:hidden} might help

Comment: sorry, you can watch it now ^^

Comment: {overflow: hidden} didn't do the trick

Comment: sorry, not seeing it.

Comment: that's strange, I made the video unlisted so you should be able to see it

Comment: Oh, very sorry to be unclear, I could see the video, I just couldn't see the glitch.

Comment: oh... you have to watch the social sites links on the bottom left corner of the screen. When I am in Chrome (first 7 seven seconds), the separate links (facebook, twitter, g+) glitches when resizing down. The white background flashes as the links sort of get {margin-bottom: 1px}. On the 8th second, the Firefox part begins, where the glitch doesn't occur.

Comment: Hey Michal, use `transform: scale()` instead of `width` and `height`. Also if you want to reposition your elements and animate it with CSS, dont use `left,right,bottom,top`. Use `transform: translate()`.

Comment: this worked perfectly, thanks :)